# About properties of invertible operators

Tags: operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $S\in\mathcal{L}(X)$ be a bounded invertible operator.

Take $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ two subspaces of $X$ such that $X_{1}\subseteq X_{2}$ and consider $S: X_{1}\rightarrow X_{2}.$ This operator still invertible from $X_{1}$ to $X_{2}$?

Comment: the general theorem is almost trivial : if $S$ is bounded and $A \cap ker(S) = \{0\}$, then $S_A : A \to S(A)$ is invertible. and its inverse is bounded iff $\inf_{x \in A \setminus \{0\}} \frac{\|S(x)\|}{\|x\|} > 0$

Answer (score 1):

A priori you cannot guarantee that  $S $ will map $X_1$ into $X_2$. The necessary condition is also sufficient : the restriction of $S $ to $X_1$ will be invertible if and only if  $X_2=SX_1$.

Comment: Now, let $A\in{\mathcal{C}}(X),$ is a closed linear operator with dense domain $\mathcal{D}(A)$ and $S\in\mathcal{L}(X)$ is invertible operator. Suppose that there exist a positive integer
$n$ such that
$S:{\cal{D}}(A^n)\rightarrow{\cal{D}}(A)$ and satisfying $\forall~x\in{\cal{D}}(A^n),~~ASx = SAx.$,  can we consider that $S$ is also invertible from ${\cal{D}}(A^n)$ to ${\cal{D}}(A)$ ?